# Installing Openssl3.x on Rhel 8 running into warnings

Tags: openssl, rhel8

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.1.1, needed by //usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2, may conflict with libcrypto.so.3

Rhel 8 comes by default with openssl 1.1.1 . Openssl 3.x was installed manually on the Rhel 8.
After which while running a client application I run into the above warning.

## openssl version

OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021

When I checked the version .. It still says openssl 1.1.1 . Do we need to uninstall openssl 1.1.1  before installing the new one? ( i am unaware of how the installation was done, I was given an AI to debug the above warning)

Otherwise also What does this warning mean? What needs to be done to avoid fixing this conflict?